# SELinux denies "systemctl kill" when used in Anacron postrotate script on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, cron, systemd, selinux, logrotate

I'm using backup software called UrBackup, which I've configured to rotate its logs once a day through cron.daily. After the logs are rotated, the software uses a postrotate script to send the running process a HUP signal with "systemctl kill". However, SELinux is denying this operation, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Here is the entire logrotate config file for UrBackup from /etc/logrotate.d:

```
"/var/log/urbackup.log" {
        daily
        rotate 30
        missingok
        create 640 urbackup urbackup
        compress
        postrotate
                test -e /var/run/urbackupsrv.pid && kill -HUP 'cat /var/run/urbackupsrv.pid' || /bin/systemctl kill -s HUP urbackup-server.service
        endscript
}
```

As I've found, the following problematic postrotate script is being executed on the system:

```
/bin/systemctl kill -s HUP urbackup-server.service
```

SELinux is blocking this. Here is the relevant log entry from /var/log/messages:

```
Nov 14 03:33:33 backup4 kernel: type=1107 audit(1510648413.518:4407695): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='avc:  denied  { stop } for auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 path="/usr/lib/systemd/system/urbackup-server.service" cmdline="/bin/systemctl kill -s HUP urbackup-server.service" scontext=system_u:system_r:logrotate_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 tclass=service#012 exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" sauid=0 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

Nov 14 03:33:33 backup4 logrotate: ALERT exited abnormally with [1]
```

Because the HUP signal is not sent to the service, it doesn't know that the logfiles have been rotated, and it continues writing indefinitely into an old (rotated) log.

I tried to troubleshoot this using the sealert utility to provide an explanation of all errors in /var/log/audit/audit.log. However, it appears to ignore this error, even though the log entry appears in audit.log.

I also tried running the "systemctl kill" command interactively as root. It completes without any error. The same goes for a manual running of logrotate:

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/urbackup-server
```

That command also runs without problems. **The only time I'm seeing the SELinux denial is when logrotate is triggered by the daily Anacron process.**

Is the "systemctl kill" command explicitly not allowed by SELinux? If so, why can I run it interactively, but not when started through cron? Is there any way I can add an exception for this case, or another way I can send the HUP signal to the process so it will write into the correct log file?

Thank you very much for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically, context `logrotate_t` is not allowed `systemd_unit_file_t`. Your interactive run of it is in a different context.

Curious that it fell through the pid file test. If that pid file does not exist while the service is running, try adding `PIDFile=/var/run/urbackupsrv.pid` to the `urbackup-server.service` unit.

There are ways to define domain transition in SELinux, but give the pid file thing a go first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpful comment. I didn't know how to find out whether the logrotate process was allowed to act on systemd unit files. SELinux is still mysterious to me :-). I'll definitely look more closely at the pid issue to see what's going on there.

Comment: Short update: According to the developer, the pid file isn't generated when the process is started with systemd -- it's only used for systems with the SysV-style init system. The developer suggests that I instead try using the postrotate command `kill -HUP $(pidof urbackupsrv)`. I don't know if this will run into the same SELinux issue, but I'm trying it now.

Comment: It appears the fix is to use the following postrotate command: `/usr/bin/kill -HUP $(pidof urbackupsrv)`. Apparently this doesn't run into any SELinux restrictions, whereas the similar `systemctl kill` command will. Thank you for your valuable help.